# Angular Universal SSR TransferState only first page data available

Tags: angular, angular-universal, static-generator, angular-transfer-state

I've created an ApiService using the TransferState API to cache data from a wordpress:

```
get(url, id) {
  const key = makeStateKey(id);
  if (this.transferState.hasKey(key)) {
    const item = this.transferState.get(key, null);
    return of(item);
  } else {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(items => {
        this.transferState.set(key, items);
        return items;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Then i'm using it to get data:

```
this.apiService.get(environment.url + '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').subscribe(res => {
  this.posts = res;
});
```

This works well, and when run, calls the API the first time, then second time is always cached.

When statically generated:

/index.html

```
<script id="my-app-state" type="application/json">
  <!-- top level page data -->
</script>
```

/posts/index.html

```
<script id="my-app-state" type="application/json">
  <!-- top level page data -->
  <!-- posts data -->
</script>
```

- If I land on the exact html page /posts/index.html, the data is loaded from the TransferState cache
  https://kmturley.github.io/angular-universal-wordpress-cms/frontend/dist/browser/sample-page
- If I land on /index.html, and navigate to /posts it uses html5 routes, the data is not available in the script tag. and is loaded via http instead
  https://kmturley.github.io/angular-universal-wordpress-cms/frontend/dist/browser/

From what I understand the reason is because you land on a real static index.html file, containing the  then when navigating, all subsequent pages are not loading .html files, they are actually html5 routes /posts.

So the question is, how can I get the TransferState cache to use the  from the /posts/index.html file which was statically generated?

Potential solutions:

- Loading all data upfront (works, but pages are 1.1MB each)
- Putting data into a static file which can be loaded by ajax
- disabling html5 routing, so user hits static .html file with correct script tag
- some undocumented angular solution??

Static generated demo:

https://kmturley.github.io/angular-universal-wordpress-cms/frontend/dist/browser/

Static generated source:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-wordpress-cms/tree/gh-pages/frontend/dist/browser

Full codebase is here:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-wordpress-cms

Comment: TransferState data will only be available for data that has been loaded server side. It's purpose is to avoid making the same request twice (once when pre-rendering, and the same one when the actual angular app takes over). As you pointed out, when you navigate from `/index.html` to `/posts`, it's a client side navigation, using angular's router. So no TransferData is available then for `/posts`. What's the problem with making a call to wordpress api?

Comment: I want everything to be static, to reduce load and security for WordPress. And considering the data is there, just in another index.html file, there should be a way to do it? I might have to hack together a solution

Comment: If you want everything static, you'd need to pre-render all the pages. Angular universal can do that for you. Then you could deactivate the router client side somehow, as you suggested.  But it's not really the angular way

Comment: I created a workaround by generating static json files! https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-wordpress-cms/commit/b495604a7f5e4e7ab3194aa01456690540a9cbb8 not proud of it's hackiness though

Comment: It's better than deactivating the router, you should not feel bad about it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using a workaround. I created a new TransferState JSON which returns data as JSON, which can be shared between multiple pages:

```
export function serializeTransferStateFactory(
    doc: Document, appId: string, transferStore: TransferState) {
  return () => {
    return JSON.parse(transferStore.toJson());
  };
}
```

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-google-apis/blob/master/src/app/shared/transfer_state_json.ts

and then modified the renderModuleFactory to return html and data separately:

```
const callbacks = moduleRef.injector.get(BEFORE_APP_SERIALIZED, null);
let data = null;
if (callbacks) {
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    try {
      data = callback();
    } catch (e) {
      // Ignore exceptions.
      console.warn('Ignoring BEFORE_APP_SERIALIZED Exception: ', e);
    }
  }
}
const output = platformState.renderToString();
platform.destroy();
return {
  output: output,
  data: data
};
```

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-google-apis/blob/master/utils.ts#L53

so that it can be saved to a .json file in prerender.ts:

```
previousRender = previousRender.then(_ => renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
  document: index,
  url: route,
  extraProviders: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
})).then((res: { output: string, data: object }) => {
  // write html file
  writeFileSync(join(fullPath, 'index.html'), res.output);

  // write json files from TransferState objects
  Object.keys(res.data).forEach(item => {
    writeFileSync(join(jsonPath, item + '.json'), JSON.stringify(res.data[item]));
  });
});
```

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-google-apis/blob/master/prerender.ts#L53

You can see a demo static version using the json here:

https://kimturley.co.uk/angular-universal-google-apis/dist/browser/

and the source code here:

https://github.com/kmturley/angular-universal-google-apis